# Can we Cast SObject dynamically in Salesforce(apex)?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, force.com

Is it possible to Cast SObject dynamically?

Example :

I know we can do this :

```
(Account) Sobject
```

But I want to do this as the return type of sObject changes based on certain parameters.

```
(Dynamically Passing the Name) SObject
```

Any Kind of way around will be helpful... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe that the short answer is no, because you still have to assign it to a strongly-typed variable.

Comment: Not direct casting, but you can play with some extension using the Type class? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm

Comment: The Type class only allows you to instantiate a new class based on a type.  It does not allow you to recast an already instantiated object.

Comment: Here is the similar  to your question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89087/type-class-and-casting-to-sobject , maybe it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. For example -

```
Class ABC {

   public static List<Object> method1(String sObjectType){
      List<Object> records = new List<Object>();
      if(sObjectType == 'Account'){
          records = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
      } else if(sObjectType == 'Account'){
          records = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact];
      }
      return records;
   }

}
```

You can check the sObject Type of List -

```
if(records instanceof List<Account>){
  // your code here
} else if(records instanceof List<Contact>){
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Using the fairly new "switch" statement can also solve part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  I ran into this recently while writing a TestFactory class.  The best I could do was cast the responses back into the expected type in the code that was calling the TestFactory's methods.